# Need to retrieve administrator password without rebooting

Tags: windows, passwords, administrator

Case:

- I'm using new work PC;
- I can open admin command prompt;
- I don't know admin password;
- I use my PC as dummy/development local server, so my PC shouldn't down for a long period of time;
- `runas /user:root` or `runas /user:administrator` ask for password;
- I can't `runas` anymore 'cause I've failed many times for trying to use password that my boss gave me (Apparently, my boss forgot it too).

Is there any ways for me to retrieve admin password without rebooting my computer?

I'm aware that this question has been asked multiple times. But, I need something that didn't require reboot.

Comment: Which Windows OS?

Comment: Is this question not "How to hack my IT department?" i.e., off-topic for in here?

Comment: No it's not, @Tetsujin. If you see the 6th point, my boss also forgot the password. I'll try some password cracker program this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, your two options are:-

1) Try a password cracker like Ophcrack (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/ophcrack.htm)

2) Reinstall Windows

Both of the options require resetting the machine however, passwords where obviously designed to be very secure, there is no real "tick box" solution to recovering a lost administrator password.

Comment: Should give it a try this night.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
net user <username> password
```

from admin command prompt

more at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394

if that does not work you can try offline NT password and registry editor here:

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

Comment: I don't like downvoting, that's not me. Anyway, it didn't work.

Comment: NT password editor works, just you have to save changes at the end. used it many times.

Comment: This will only work if you're logged in with an account having administrator privileges in the first place.  Non-admin users cannot reset/change the password for any account but their own.

Comment: @Twisty - he said he can open an Admin command prompt. For a full tutorial on how to use offline NT password and registry editor check here http://blog.cyberkenny.net/?p=6

Comment: The OP did say that, but I don't think that's what he means, since that would imply he's logged in with a user account to which he knows his own password, and his account already has admin permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Resetting the Administrator password of Windows while Windows is running would be a security problem in Windows.

Use a Linux live dvd such as Ubuntu, and boot from it.

Browse to you Windows HDD, and move the file Windows/system32/UtilMan.exe to Utilman.exe.old.

Now, copy cmd.exe to utilman.exe and reboot. Click on the accessibility icon in the left down corner. Enter:
`net user <username> password`

To reset the password. Don't forget to move utilman back!

Comment: "Is there any ways for me to retrieve admin password **without rebooting my computer**?"

Answer (score -1):

Download Hiren's BootCD. That has a password changer utility in it, and you can even make more windows admins. Would post a link, but on mobile.

Comment: "Is there any ways for me to retrieve admin password **without rebooting my computer**?"